# Passar dados por POST com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Em uma página eu carrego uma lista de pessoas com um checkbox ao lado de cada uma.
Quero passar para a página seguinte todas as pessoas que eu selecionei.
Estou tentando fazer assim:

Neste código abaixo eu verifico quem está selecionado e adiciono na variável nips.
Esse código funciona perfeitamente.

```
$(".check:checked").each(function(){       
     if($(".check:checked").is(':checked')) 
     {          var nip = $(this).parent().next( 'td' ).text(); 
                nips.push(nip);   
     } 
  }) ;
```

Agora nesse código abaixo eu passo por post a variável nips(um vetor).
Esse código funciona em parte.

```
$.ajax({             
       type: "POST",
       data: { nips:nips },             
       url: "../pdfporturma.php",
      dataType: "html"           
    });
```

Porque em parte? Porque ele não direciona para a outra página(../pdfporturma.php).
Pelo firebug eu vejo o resultado correto, mostrando os itens do vetor tudo certinho, mas
não consigo passar para essa outra página carregando esses dados.

```
Resposta do firebug:
array(1) {
["nips"]=>
array(2) {
[0]=>
string(8) "85808610"
[1]=>
string(7) "6506224"
}
}
```

Como eu faço? Já tentei window.open mas não passa os dados.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode olhar a documentação do [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Segue abaixo um exemplo de como eu faria!

```
$.ajax({
   url : '../pdfprotuna.php',
   dataType : 'html',
   type : 'POST',
   data : {npis : npis},
   beforeSend : function () {
         console.log('Carregando...');
   },
   success : function(retorno){
       alert(retorno);
   },
   error : function(a,b,c){
       alert('Erro: ' + a['status'] + ' ' + c);
   }
});
```

> Para passar dados por post em uma nova janela.

```
 <form name="teste" id="form_id_teste" action="teste.php" method="POST" target="BLANK">
     <input type="text" name="teste" value="Valor de teste" />
 </form>
 <script>
    $('#form_id_teste').submit();
 </script>
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou. Simplesmente não abre a página com os dados para eu trabalhar. Eu queria que abrisse de preferência em uma nova aba. Nesse arquivo php de destino eu uso a classe fpdf para gerar várias cartas em um único arquivo pdf.

Comment: aaah sim, entendi oque você quis dizer

Comment: mais ai, você não poderia recuperar um PDF via AJAX

Comment: tem uma forma melhor

Comment: cria um form do tipo post ai você faz o procedimento padrão com ele ai você colocaria o atributo target="BLANK" e o method como post ai você colocava uma propriedade css para deixar ele oculto. Ai você atribui um ID e usa o $('#id_do_form').submit() ai ele vai passar por post em uma nova janela.

Comment: Coloquei na resposta um exemplo.

Comment: @HiagoSouza no meu caso que no form é o que vem do mysql , ele não tem name"algumacoisa" como posso fazer

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi, vc que cria o documento HMTL correto?

Comment: @HiagoSouza o meu form é dinâmico , a tabela de pedido vem do mysql via ajax e jquery , daí o usuário clica sobre os pedidos que ele quer . Como faço pra mandar o que foi seleciona para o mysql , sendo que se fosse um form com name"alguma coisa " ficaria fácil mas o meu form é dinâmico não tem name"" como posso fazer ?

Answer (score 1):

Falta o marcador `success: function(data) {$('#').html(data);}`

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "tipo de requisição... GET ou POST",
        data: { seus dados },
        url: "sua página",
        success: function(data) { //Se a requisição retornar com sucesso, 
        //ou seja, se o arquivo existe, entre outros
                $('#').html(data); //Parte do seu 
                //HTML que voce define onde sera carregado o conteudo
                //PHP, por default eu uso uma div, mas da pra fazer em outros lugares
            }
        });
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou. Simplesmente não abre a página com os dados para eu trabalhar. Eu queria que abrisse de preferência em uma nova aba. Nesse arquivo php de destino eu uso a classe fpdf para gerar várias cartas em um único arquivo pdf.

Comment: velho... o intuito do jquery é carregar algo dentro da própria página...
nesse caso acho que voce estaria usando um elefante branco em algo que um simples form action poderia suprimir

Answer (score 1):

Se as checkboxes estiverem dentro de uma form, pode enviar a data da seguinte maneira

```
data : $( "form" ).serialize(),
```

Assim, não precisa daquele passo extra para checar as boxes seleccionadas antes de submeter a form.

Comment: isso poderia funcionar para meu caso já que o meu form é dinâmico . http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181981/form-din%C3%A2mico-e-envio-para-o-mysql-via-jquery-e-ajax?noredirect=1#comment376494_181981